# Redisson client: retrieve top N keys

Tags: redis, redisson

How can i get top of N keys from [redisson client](https://github.com/redisson/)?

I found next signature in `getKeysByPattern()` method:

```
Iterable<String> getKeysByPattern(String pattern, int count);
```

But looks like `count` - is keys loaded per request to Redis.

How can i load top N keys from Redis via redisson client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getKeysByPattern()` is not valid for such case, right.

It's better to use lua scripts here:

```
val luaScript = "return {redis.call('SCAN',ARGV[1],'MATCH',ARGV[2],'COUNT',ARGV[3])}"
var cursor = 0
do {
  val data = redissonClient
                .getScript(StringCodec.INSTANCE)
                .eval(RScript.Mode.READ_ONLY,
                        luaScript,
                        RScript.ReturnType.MAPVALUELIST,
                        listOf(),
                        cursor,
                        "some-pattern",
                        batchSize)


  val redistListData = (data[0][1] as List<String>)
  cursor = data[0][0].toInt()
} while (cursor != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `RKeys.getKeysWithLimit(String pattern, int limit)` method for this case.